# Adding a button to JWplayer control bar to control javascript

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

We feed JWplayer with an external playlist, and have an external button to shuffle this play list. I would like to move this button into the JWplayer control bar itself.

I'm not a developer, I'm a designer - but, thanks to a link found on the JWplayer support forum I have been able to add a custom button to the control bar - via the skin.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forum/Skins/13043/Adding-custom-buttons-to-the-control-bar

However, I have a problem in getting the button to work. Speaking with the developer I need to provide an ExternalInterface function which will take the name of a javascript function (e.g. setShuffleFunction('window.toggleButton') ), and then call the javascript function with true/false (depending on the button state) when the button is clicked. I've spent hours looking in forums, and on Google and am unable to find an answer. Are you able to advise me? Thank you for your time.

kind regards,
Rob Willie

Comment: Were you able to get it done? Can you post the solution if you got it done?

Comment: You can see my answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36430044/1386969
Hope it help

Comment: You can see my answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36430044/1386969 Dont forget to smile :)

Comment: You can see my answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36430044/1386969 Dont forget to smile :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have the Javascript function written. You can call your external javascript function with the flash.external.ExternalInterface;

eg.

```
function myButton_Click(e:MouseEvent)
{
    ExternalInterface.call("myJSFunction", true);
}
```

"myJSFunction" is your javascript function.

This page provides more explaination.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html