# How to add an additional button to the controlbar with jwplayer 7

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am interested in adding a download video button, similar to the one here -- http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1436999-example-adding-a-download-button. However, I would like to add it within the control bar (a download arrow to the far right).

How would I add in additional buttons to the controlbar in jwplayer 7?

Comment: This is really for just adding dock buttons. We do not have APIs for adding buttons to the control bar, I'm afraid.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I am using lidox's solution to add to the controlbar but can't seem to get the onClick event working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
playerInstance.on('ready',function() {
                    if (jwplayer().getRenderingMode() == "html5"){
                        videoTag = document.querySelector('video');
                         if(videoTag.playbackRate) {
                            playerInstance.addButton(
                                "icon_dir.png",
                                "0.25x", 
                                function() {
                                  changeSpeed(0.25);
                                },
                                "0p25xslow"
                            );

                            playerInstance.addButton(
                                "icon_dir.png",
                                "0.5x", 
                                function() {
                                  changeSpeed(0.5);
                                },
                                "0p5slow"
                            );

                            playerInstance.addButton(
                                "icon_dir.png",
                                "1x", 
                                function() {
                                  changeSpeed(1);
                                },
                                "1xnormal"
                            );

                            playerInstance.addButton(
                                "icon_dir.png",
                                "1.5x", 
                                function() {
                                  changeSpeed(1.5);
                                },
                                "1p5xforward"
                            );

                            playerInstance.addButton(
                                "icon_dir.png",
                                "2x", 
                                function() {
                                  changeSpeed(2);
                                },
                                "2xforward"
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("your browser doesn't support HTML5，cant't change speed.");
                    }
                    console.log("state is :"+playerInstance.getState());
                });
```

Comment: You forgot to close the quotes after "icon_dir.png at 3rd button

Answer (score 4):

For JW Player 7.3 you can do this via JS

```
    playerInstance.onReady(function(){
            var myLogo = document.createElement("div");
            myLogo.id = "myTestLogo";
            myLogo.setAttribute('style',"color: red; padding-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 10px; background-image: url('/icon_dir.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;");
            myLogo.setAttribute('class','jw-icon jw-icon-inline jw-button-color jw-reset jw-icon-logo');
            myLogo.setAttribute('onclick','window.location="http://jwplayer.com"');
            document.getElementsByClassName('jw-controlbar-right-group')[0].appendChild(myLogo);
    });
```

Comment: nice solution! I used it to insert a button for resizing the player. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to use this pattern with a React component, instead of using document.createElement?

Comment: sorry, I never used react before. maybe you open an issue/question?

Comment: I actually figured that bit out, but I am wondering if the onclick event was working for you? It did not work for me and I am trying to add my own event listener but it seems that there is no onclick event happening

Comment: @crobicha How did you managed to add react component ?